# Ensuring the information after ? is an integer

Tags: php, validation, hyperlink, sanitization

I've moved from HTML to PHP coding, so when I wanted to make a link for my news page I used HREF to take the id for the row as a link and make the title of the piece the viewable/clickable link:

```
echo "<a href=news.php?id=".$row{'id'};
echo ">";
echo ucwords(strtolower($row{'newstitle'}));
echo "</a>";
```

So when someone clicks on the title it redirects to the article and the address bar becomes (obviously this is an example):
http://site.com/news.php?id=1

How can I validate that the information after the ? is id=int (it will always be a number) and not some user code or other input that could damage the site? I've looked at ways of Sanitizing/Validating the code, but all the examples I've found have been to do with entering information into forms that are then used in the address rather than simply ensuring the address is valid, hence turning to here for assistance. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [filter module](http://php.net/filter):

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if ($id === false) {
     // not an integer
}
```

Or you can use [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/ctype_digit) to check if a variable is composed only of decimal digits:

```
if (ctype_digit($_GET['id'])) {
    // it's an integer
} else {
    // not an integer
}
```

Or shorter:

```
ctype_digit($_GET['id']) or die("oops that's not an integer!");
```

But `die` or `exit` would make your code less testable.

---

[`is_numeric`](http://php.net/is_numeric) would work too, but it would return true for any string representation of a number, not only integers.

Comment: This will not *check* that the input is a valid representation of an integer.

Comment: It will now... way to cover up a duff answer.

Comment: dying is always a bad practice

Comment: I tend to agree, this was only for adding something after the if :)

Comment: It's nice that you think about testing in your answer, but actually running the filter functions against `INPUT_GET` prevents testing as well. Just saying :)

Comment: Thank you, ended up using: 
     
            if(!ctype_digit($id)){
            echo "That is not a valid id";
           }

           $query="select * from podcast where id = '$id'";

(yes that's code, but it won't recognise the indenting)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
if (is_int($_GET["id"])) {
echo "is integer\n";
} else {
echo "is not an integer\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: $_GET "integers" are actually string values. Use [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have excluded `0` as a valid number for your integer id, you can simply do the following:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
if (!$id) {
    # no number -or- 0 given
} else {
   # regardless what have been given, it has been converted at least to some integer.
}
```

That's by casting. Now `$id` is always an integer so more safe to use.

However, most often you need to check as well that the number is non-negative:

```
$id = max(0, $_GET['id']);
```

The `max` function does take care of casting `$_GET['id']` into an integer. It ensures that the id is 0 or higher in case the provided value was greater than 0. If it was 0 or lower, 0 is the maximum number.

If you then need to actually validate the input more strictly, you can turn it back into a string for comparison reasons:

```
if ("$id" === $_GET['id'])
{
   # Input was done as a string representation of the integer value.
}
```